# LibGDX dragging a texture

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics

I am experimenting with LibGDX and Java and I am wanting to have a texture move along the x axis according to the users finger position if their finger is touching another texture. Below is my code, which works but only when moving your finger to the right

```
game.batch.begin();
game.batch.draw(userCar, carCord.x, carCord.y);
game.batch.draw(touchBound, touchCord.x, touchCord.y);
game.batch.end();

if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
    Rectangle textureBounds=new Rectangle(touchCord.x,touchCord.y,touchCord.width,touchCord.height);
    touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    camera.unproject(touchPos);
    if(textureBounds.contains(touchPos.x,touchPos.y) {
        carCord.x = touchPos.x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a few details to take into account.

1) You should give a bit more of information about your problem.

2) That `game.batch.draw(touchBound, touchCord.x, touch.y);` with `touch.y` instead of `touchCord.y` looks really suspicious. Check it out.

3) As a function of how are you handling those positions and texture sizes, you should not unproject the touch position, or you should assign the texture x accordingly.

4) Also remember the direction of the Y axis. It may be pointing up and you would asking if the touch is inside it with wrong coordinates.

Hope it helps.